# Estou com um problema no Terminal do VsCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
v = float(input('Valor: R$ '))
b = 5.33
print(f'U$ {v * b:.2f}')
```

Quando eu faço algum código com input, da um erro no terminal após algum tempo sem digitar algo.

```
Erro: invalid literal for int() with base ou could not convert string to float
```

Comment: Eu tenho uma ideia do que seja, mas para confirmar gostaria que você me colocasse um exemplo de input para o script.

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente está digitando um valor com a `","` (vírgula) como separador decimal ex: `1,23`, experimente digitar o número com a casa decimal separada por ponto `"."` ex: `1.23`.

Outra alternativa é adicionar um tratamento para o `input` antes de converter para `float` com o método `.replace()`, substituindo a vírgula pelo ponto:

```py
v = float(input('Valor: R$ ').replace(",", "."))
b = 5.33
print(f'U$ {v * b:.2f}')
```